# Designing GUI for WiX installer: Edit is not user-editable

Tags: xml, user-interface, wix

I am working on a custom dialog. I have a radio button control, 3 text controls and 2 Edit controls. My issue is that the upper control seems to be disabled and cannot be edited. What am I doing wrong? I am not getting any errors, I just cannot interact with one of the edit controls. The radio button works fine.

```
<Property Id="YESNO" Value="1" />

<Dialog Id="SkyBlueORNot" Width="370"
   Height="270"
   Title="Sky blue or not"
   NoMinimize="no">

<Control Id="SupervisorUserControl"
    Type="Text"
    X="40" 
    Y="40"
    Width="200"
    Height="17"
    Text="Is the sky blue?" />            

<Control Id="SkyBlue"
        Type="RadioButtonGroup" 
        Property="YESNO"
        Width="100" 
        Height="100" 
        X="50" 
        Y="60">
            <RadioButtonGroup Property="YESNO">
                 <RadioButton Value="1" 
                 Text="Yes" 
                 Height="17" 
                 Width="250" 
                 X="0" 
                 Y="0" />
                 <RadioButton Value="2" 
                 Text="No" 
                 Height="17" 
                 Width="250" 
                 X="0" 
                 Y="20" />
            </RadioButtonGroup>
        </Control>

    <Control Id="IP1Text" Type="Text" X="40" Y="100" Width="200" Height="17" Text="Enter IP Address1:" />   
    <Control Id="IP1Edit" Type="Edit" Property="IP1" Text= "Cowabunga" Height="17" Width="100" X="40" Y="120" />

    <Control Id="IP2Text" Type="Text" X="40" Y="140" Width="200" Height="17" Text="Enter IP Address2:" />   

    <Control Id="IP2Edit" Type="Edit" Property="IP2" Height="17" Text= "Cowabunga" Width="100" X="40" Y="160" />

    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">

    </Control>
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />

</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was the radiobuttongroup causing problems on the clickable area within the Edit control elements.

I reduced the width & height of the radiobuttongroup elements until they no longer interfered with the clickable area of the edit elements.